# The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()?

Tags: python, valueerror

**The Code**

```
indices =pd.Series(df_small)

indices[ : 5]
```

**The Error**

```
The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: What is df_small here?

Comment: it is the data which i am using to create series of indices

Comment: Index(['user_id', 'song_id', 'play_count', 'text'], dtype='object')

Comment: df_small shape (704, 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason might be that your dataframe df_small might have more than one column i.e it is not of Series datatype rather its a DataFrame, hence it is showing that error.

Try with only one column and you might not face the above error. For eg

```
indices = pd.Series(df_small.col1)
```

Comment: if you want to create index for your dataframe , you can also do the following.

Comment: indexs = list(range(0, df_small.shape[0])), df_small.index = indexs